# How to fix the len() command returning TypeError?

Tags: python

I am trying to work out the length of a string in python however I can't seem to get a correct response. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful. 
Code:

```
name = input("Type a string!")
name = name.upper
lenname = len(name)
if lenname == 3:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

I expect the output to be `Success` when I enter `abc` however I receive:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-20-1de45569cf05> in <module>
      1 name = input("Type a string!")
      2 name = name.upper
----> 3 lenname = len(name)
      4 if lenname == 3:
      5     print("Sucess")

TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

Comment: Use `name = name.upper()`

Comment: Adding a tip on figuring this out yourself, as you already have a root cause. You could have printed the value of `name`, and realised it's not abc, but something entirely different. Always look at your variables if they aren't doing what you expect.

Comment: You didn't call the method;

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix the problem. Good tip @Danielle , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access `upper` like it's a field, not a method. On the line above where you use `len`, do `name = name.upper()`.